# Pass laravel query result to blade via ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm wondering how I can pass a laravel query result back to my ajax function on success. I've read something about json encode but I'm getting kind of confused as how I can do so, not really familiar with json that much.

#### Ajax

```
$('#userFilter').change(function(){
    var selected = $('#userFilter').find(':selected').val();
    var token = $('#token').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin_panel',
        data: {
            _token : token,
            selected : selected,
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#usersViewBody').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

#### Controller

```
function filterUsers(Request $request) {
    $selected = $request->selected;
    if ($selected == 0) {
        $users = DB::table('users')->paginate(15);
    } elseif ($selected == 1){
        $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('status', '=', '0')
                ->orWhere('status', '=', '1')
                ->paginate(15);
    } else {
        $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('status', '=', '2')
                ->orWhere('status', '=', '3')
                ->paginate(15);
    }

    return $users;
```

#### View

```
<tbody id="usersViewBody">
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td><a data-uid="{{$user->id}}" class="openUserPanel" href="#tabUserInfo"> {{$user->name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$user->department}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->position}}</td>
        @if($user->status == 0)
        <td class="userActive">Active</td>
        @elseif($user->status == 1)
        <td class="userOOO">On Leave</td>
        @elseif($user->status == 2)
        <td class="userInactive">Retired</td>
        @else
        <td class="userInactive">Terminated</td>
        @endif
        @if($user->status == 2 || $user->status == 3)
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-default payrollModalTrigger disabled" data-uid="{{$user->id}}">Update Payroll</button></td>
        @else
        <td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-default payrollModalTrigger" data-uid="{{$user->id}}">Update Payroll</button></td>
        @endif
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: JSON is just about the same notation as Javascript (afte all it's name means **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation)

Comment: Your controller should generate a PHP object and then [convert it to JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and send it. Then from the JS you just [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and use it as an object to generate your html. To generate the HTML I recommend you use a template engine.

Comment: Just putting the HTML like you do can be dangerous because it expose you to [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning collection `$users` from your controller you need to return `view` back to the ajax, hence change the return of the controller method from

```
return $users;
```

to

```
return view('name of the view', compact('users'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Blade is used when the page is first loaded (i.e. it's rendered on the server), it will only run again if you reload the page which is in contrast to what you're trying to do with ajax, i.e. interact with the server without a page reload.

What you want to do in your ajax success call is constrcut HTML for the contents of your table body in javascript along with the data you get in the response from the server.

This package has already done all the heavy lifting for you https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables, it would, of course, be good to learn how to do it yourself though!